Should I use Versioned Transactions instead of Legacy?
Trading on Raydium, I use Legacy transactions, but when I look at Solscan, other traders use Versioned Transactions (here's an example of such a transaction https://solscan.io/tx/5MX5WuhMY5SEa25r4ZycSQNxhRBfKMHFJ8YUGRKYMq67k1zHMyePA36eFzKJCNf7ZWFMtdgkBD1pTGJPQzRhfhKk).
I know that their advantage is that they use the AddressLookupTable to reduce the transaction size, so instead of 32 bytes for one account, only one byte is used if that account is in the AddressLookupTable (if I understand correctly). However, a Legacy transaction for a swap on Raydium should not exceed a size of 1232 bytes, as this transaction achieves its goal. So I became interested in whether the transaction size depends on how quickly it is processed by leaders or RPC clients. Or does it not matter what size the transaction is, as long as it does not exceed the 1232-byte limit?

To answer simply, it doesn't matter! You correctly pointed out the difference between legacy and versioned transactions as the ability to use address-lookup-tables, so if you don't need them, you're fine with legacy transactions.
